# Can we print the command line arguments in setup_module() or setup_class in pytest?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

I got to know how to pass command line parameters in pytest.
I want to print or do some basic validation in my setup_class() or setup_module() against the variables passed as command line arguments.

I am able to access these variables in test methods but not in setup_class or setup_module. Is this even possible?

I want to do something like this...

**conftest.py**

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--user',action='store', help='email id Ex: abc@infoblox.com')
```

**test_1.py**

```
import pytest

def setup_module():
    print 'Setup Module'
def teardown_module():
    print "Teardown Module"

class Test_ABC:

    def setup_class(cls,request):
        user = request.config.option.user
        print user
        print 'Setup Class'

    def teardown_class(cls,request):
        print 'Teardown Class'

    def test_12(self,request):
        print "Test_12"
        assert 1==1
```

Answer (score 5):

In conftest.py:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    """Add the --user option"""
    parser.addoption(
        '-U', '--user',
        action="store", default=None,
        help="The user")

option = None

def pytest_configure(config):
    """Make cmdline arguments available to dbtest"""
    global option
    option = config.option
```

Now you can just import `option` from `conftest`:

```
from conftest import option

class Test_ABC:

    def setup_class(cls):
        user = option.user
        print user
        print 'Setup Class'
```

Comment: i am sorry but i don't understand how my test.py file should be like. Can you please elaborate. Thanks

Comment: I extended the answer.

Comment: I get this error when i run the test. Could you tell me where i am wrong.
`py.test test_2.py --user="mkunja@infoblox.com" -vvs`
`usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]`
`py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: --user=mkunja@infoblox.com`
`inifile: None`
 `rootdir: /mnt/home/mverma/manoj/py`

Comment: I added `pytest_addoption` to the answer.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me . I tried executing with pytest test_1.py --user="manoj" and i get this error `ValueError: lowercase shortoptions reserved`

Comment: Updated once again. Replaced option `-u` with `-U` (`--user` stays).

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar use case and I ended up implementing it as follows:

In conftest.py

```
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--testarg", action="store", dest="testarg", default="test", help="testarg help")

def pytest_configure(config):
    pytest.testarg = config.getoption('testarg')
```

In test_sample.py

```
import pytest
print pytest.testarg
```

Resources:

1. https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_addoption

Answer (score 2):

1.Add conftest.py at first and add 2 method in it.

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--devicename", action="store", default="test1", help="test1"
    )

def pytest_configure(config):
    pytest.devicename = config.getoption('devicename')
```

2.Then call pytest. in your setupclass or setupmethod.
like 
`print(pytest.devicename)`