# How to access config.option command line argument in test script with py.test framework

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

I am taking value of `setup` from command line argument while running the test with py.test framework.

```
group.addoption("--setup", "--sC=", action="store", dest="setup", help="setup.")
def pytest_configure(config):
    print "config.option.setup: ", config.option.setup
```

Here, I am able to get the setup file name with `config.option.setup`, but the same file name which I pass here, I want to fetch it from my test script.

If I put the same line in my test script, I get below error:

```
>       print "config.option.setup_config: ", config.option.setup_config
E       NameError: global name 'config' is not defined
```

Can someone please let me know how can I access config.option.setup in my test script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we print the command line arguments in setup\_module() or setup\_class in pytest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45120266/can-we-print-the-command-line-arguments-in-setup-module-or-setup-class-in-pyte)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pytest_configure` must be in the file `conftest.py`. See [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45128285/7976758):

```
option = None

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--setup", "--sC=", action="store", dest="setup", help="setup.")

def pytest_configure(config):
    global option
    option = config.option
    print "config.option.setup: ", config.option.setup
```

Comment: I updated the answer. Save global `option` and import it in the test script: `from conftest import option`.

Comment: Nope. Do not import from conftest: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#conftest-py-local-per-directory-plugins
If you have conftest.py files which do not reside in a python package directory (i.e. one containing an __init__.py) then “import conftest” can be ambiguous because there might be other conftest.py files as well on your PYTHONPATH or sys.path.

Answer (score 4):

You have to create a fixture that extracts this value from pytest's `request`.

```
# content of conftest.py
import pytest


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--setup", action="store", help="setup.")


@pytest.fixture
def setup_option(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--setup")


# basic usage:
# content of test_anything.py

def test_that(setup_option):
    print("setup_option: %s" % setup_option)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also define a function that adds the option to the parser and creates a fixture to access that custom option so you don't have to define a fixture function for every single custom option.

```py
def addoption_with_fixture(
    parser,
    *opts,
    fixture_name: Optional[str] = None,
    fixture_args: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None,
    fixture_callable: Optional[Callable[..., Any]] = None,
    **attrs,
) -> None:
    """
    Adds a custom option to pytest and in addition adds a pytest fixture function to the module. If a callable isn't
    passed to fixture_callable a simple fixture will be created that returns the value passed to the cli.
    """
    parser.addoption(*opts, **attrs)
    lambda_callable = lambda pytestconfig: pytestconfig.getoption(opts[0])  # noqa: E731
    # name is equivalent to the fixture's function name (what's passed to other fixture functions as arguments).
    name = fixture_name or (
        fixture_callable.__name__
        if (fixture_callable and fixture_callable.__name__ != "<lambda>")
        else get_valid_variable_name(opts[0])
    )
    f = pytest.fixture(fixture_callable or lambda_callable, **(fixture_args or {}), name=name)
    setattr(sys.modules[__name__], name, f)


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    addoption_with_fixture(parser, "--foo", action="store", default=True)
    addoption_with_fixture(parser, "--bar", action="store", default="main")
    addoption_with_fixture(parser, "--foo-bar", action="store", default=True)
    addoption_with_fixture(
        parser,
        "--baz",
        action="store",
        default="bang",
        fixture_args=dict(scope="session"),
        fixture_callable=lambda pytestconfig: Path(pytestconfig.getoption("baz")),
        fixture_name="im_passed_to_other_fixtures",
    )
```